# Initialization Vector in encryption

Tags: asp.net

I've never done any encryption before, but I've been all over MSDN and google. I finally got something working.

I've seen this a ton of times:

```
Dim IV() As Byte = {&H12, &H34, &H56, &H78, &H90, &HAB, &HCD, &HEF}.
```

My question is this - do the hex digits inside the array have any significance? I just find it terribly odd that these particular numbers would be used SO often otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter. Anything can be in the initialization vector (as long as both sides use the same values in the vector). These values are used in examples because they are simple...

Read more about the initialization vector [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector).

Comment: Thanks. I thought so, but to find the same values so many times made me really wonder.

Comment: Wow, it wasn't until I was driving home that I realized that those numbers were 1-0 and a-d. I need a vacation.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a simple sample byte array.

In real applications, your IV should be randomly generated using [`RNGCryptoServiceProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.aspx), and should be different for each ciphertext.

Answer (score 1):

Those hex numbers are used to generate the encryption keys that are used to do the encryption.  If I might make a suggestion, you might want to check out the [Enterprise Library Cryptography Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664484(v=PandP.50).aspx), it can do a lot of the dirty work for you.